# Connect to database Sql server database 2000

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, sql-server-2000

When running SQL Source Control in SSMS 2017 I'm unable to expand any of my databases in object explorer on a 2000 server, I have connected. If I open a second instance of SSMS (so SQL Source Control is disabled) it works.
I want to connect database SQL 2000 from visual studio 2017, netcore 2.2, but it returns an error:

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

This is my C# code:

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, conn))
    {
        if (cmdParams != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(cmdParams);
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
}

[![This is version of sql][1]][1]


Please help me ignore this issue to get data


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/goo7Y.png
```

Comment: SSMS 2017 doesn't support SQL Server 2000; I wouldn't expect it to work properly. You need to use an old (and also unsupported) version of SSMS. Certainly Redgate's SQL Source Control is not going to support a version of SQL Server that has been almost out of support for 10 years.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is that the OP is trying to use current technology with technology that has been long unsupported by the vendor. Although not a bad question, the real problem is the age of the product, and it is clearly documented that the current versions of SSMS do not support SQL Server 2000. The OP has to use an old version of SSMS or update their version of SQL Server; SSMS 2017 (and Redgate SQL Source Control) will never work with 2000.

Comment: Because I need to connect to client's data. Some of machine still sql 2000. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As mentioned though, @tamphan , 2000 is long out of support (over 6 years). If you've the vendor you can't be expected to support something that even the developer no longer does. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Documentation below, it is not supported to connect SSMS 2017 to SQL Server 2000.

[See SQL Server Management Studio  Supported SQL Server Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

SQL Server 2000 instances can be managed using earlier versions of SQL Server Management Studio, but SQL Server 2000 management from SQL Server Management Studio 2014 is not a supported scenario.

Comment: That isn't a connect bug; that's documentation. It's not a "bug" that SSMS 2017 (or even 2014+) doesn't support SQL Server 2000, it's by design; as SQL Server 2000 has been long out of support from Microsoft. If someone choose to continue to use unsupported technology, the only way to continue to gain support is by paying Microsoft some very high fees; and that won't provide you with a new version of SSMS just security updates and actual bug fixes if they affect you on the product (SQL Server 2000 in this case).